# Flask and Jinja2 TemplateSyntaxError on line 1 of the template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to create an example application using Flask. Everything was working fine but problem occurred from nowhere.

My traceback and source files are attached to this post. I'd like to mention that I've already tried to change line ending formats (UNIX-like, Windows-like) and encodings (ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-8 w/o BOM).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
  File "c:\Python27\MyProject\runserver.py", line 22, in index
    return render_template('index.html')
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 127, in render_template
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_or_select_template
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 791, in get_template
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 765, in _load_template
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 554, in compile
  File "C:\Python27\MyProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
  File "c:\Python27\MyProject\templates\index.html", line 1, in template
    {% extends "base.html" %}
TemplateSyntaxError: unicode-escape
```

Here is my runserver.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory, url_for

# initialization
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    DEBUG = True,
)

# controllers
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'ico/favicon.ico')

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/base")
def base():
    return render_template('base.html')

# launch
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

And here are my templates:

**base.html**

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        {% block head %}
        {# <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"> #}
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
        <div id="footer">
          {% block footer %}
          &copy; Copyright 2010 by <a href="http://domain.invalid/">you</a>.
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And **index.html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} - Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if not session.logged_in %}
     <p>You are not logged in.</p>
{% else %}
     <p>You are logged in.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What exact Python 2.7 version is this? Can you open up Python and try out `''.decode('unicode-escape')` in that? Does that raise an exception too?

Comment: Which program did you use to create the templates?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Python 2.7.8
>>> ''.decode('unicode-escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode-escape
>>>

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I tried both Sublime Text and Notepad++.

Comment: @NobodyOne: right, the `unicode-escape` codec is fundamental and if that is missing, then I'd call your Python installation broken.

Comment: @NobodyOne: On Windows, I'd expect a `Python27\Lib\encodings` directory to exist (although I am not 100% certain about the exact paths) with `unicode_escape.py` file in it. That appears to be missing in your case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I've already solved this by creating a new project. It's likely that you were right and i could just delete and create new virtualenv.

Comment: @NobodyOne: perhaps you created a top-level `encodings` package?